# FBX not importing, no errors in console

Tags: import, unity, .fbx

I am trying to import this model from Unity Store https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/humanoids/amanda-frost-34583 but it does not show up in the project.

Console does not output any errors:

```
\Amanda\amandaModel.fbx
FBX version: 7400
        FBX import: Prepare...
                Done (0.000000 sec)

        FBX import: Templates...
                Done (0.000000 sec)

        FBX import: Nodes...
                Done (0.000000 sec)

        FBX import: Connections...
                Done (0.000000 sec)

        FBX import: Meshes...
                Done (0.000000 sec)

        FBX import: Materials & Textures...
                Done (0.000000 sec)

        FBX import: Cameras & Lamps...
                Done (0.000000 sec)

        FBX import: Objects & Armatures...
                Done (0.000000 sec)

        FBX import: ShapeKeys...
                Done (0.000000 sec)

        FBX import: Animations...
                Done (0.000000 sec)

        FBX import: Assign materials...
                Done (0.000000 sec)

        FBX import: Assign textures...
                Done (0.000000 sec)

        FBX import: Cycles z-offset workaround...
                Done (0.000000 sec)

        Done (0.000000 sec)
```

[image]

Blender 2.79b

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of "amandaModel.fbx" is 4 kilobytes while "bullet1shell.fbx" is 17 kilobytes, that didn't seem right. I suspect the actual mesh geometry is not in the amandaModel.fbx but that was just a file where various models from files were linked into.

You can access the actual models by importing one of the animation files in the "animations" directory. Here I imported "amanda@idle.fbx".

[image: Scene hierarchy after importing]

The object relations aren't imported properly, so you have some setting up to do after importing.

[image: 3D view after importing]